# how to pass the dropdown value in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

This may be silly question but i dono....

```
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($stmodel,'student_track_class_branch',array('class'=>'col-md-4 control-label')); ?>       
            <div class="col-md-4">          
                <?php
                    $start_class=Yii::app()->user->getState('start_class');
                    $end_class=Yii::app()->user->getState('end_class');

                    $std_arr=array();
                    for($i=$start_class; $i <= $end_class; $i++)
                        $std_arr[$i]=$i.' Std';
                    echo $form->dropdownlist($stmodel,'student_track_class_branch',
                                    $std_arr,
                                    array(  'empty'=>'--Select--',
                                            'class'=>'form-control',
                                            'required'=>"required",
                                            'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                        'url'=>CController::createUrl('common/UpdateSectionView'),
                                                        'data'=>array('std_id'=>'js:$(this).val()','YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
                                                        'update'=>'#StudentTracker_student_track_sec_dept'
                                                        )
                                        )
                                    );
                ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($stmodel,'student_track_class_branch'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($stmodel,'student_track_sec_dept',array('class'=>'col-md-4 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php 
                    $sec_arr=array();
                    if(!empty($stmodel->student_track_class_branch))
                    {
                        $sec=new SchoolSectionDetails;
                        $sec_avl = $sec->get_section_limit( Yii::app()->user->role, Yii::app()->user->id, $stmodel->student_track_class_branch);

                        $sec_arr  = array();
                        if (!empty($sec_avl))
                        {
                            for ($i = 1; $i <= $sec_avl; $i++)
                                $sec_arr[$i] = $this->_school_sec[$i];
                        }
                    }
                    echo $form->dropdownlist($stmodel,'student_track_sec_dept',$sec_arr,
                                                array('empty'=>'--Select--','class'=>'form-control','required'=>"required",)); 
                ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($stmodel,'student_track_sec_dept'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'test_type',array('class'=>'col-md-4 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model, 'test_type', $this->_test_type,
                                                array(  'empty'=>'--Select--',
                                                        'class'=>'form-control',
                                                            'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                                        'url'=>$this->createUrl('MarkDetails/CreateTestView'),
                                                                        'data'=>?,
                                                                        'update'=>'#detail'
                                                                        )
                                                        )
                                                    ); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'test_type'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

on selecting test_type i need to send the value of student_track_class_branch as data in test_type via ajax if any one know how to pass this value kindly help me here.

Comment: Euh the same as you did whith the other dropdown list??

Comment: @BasvanStein ya but here its not working dono why....

Answer (score 0):

You may specify dropdown id manualy and use it or get it with [[CHtml::activeId()]] if it generated by default. So to get another dropdown value you just need this

```
'data'=> array( 'std_id' => 'js:$("#'.CHtml::activeId($stmodel,'student_track_class_branch').'").val()'
```

Comment: What exactly? @Kameshwaran

Comment: nothing is happening in url 'MarkDetails/CreateTestView' i have to print the value what i have sent here. but its not passing the value to the url

Comment: Do you replace key 'std_id' with your own?

Comment: ya i have replace not wrking

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model, 'test_type', $this->_test_type,
                                            array(  'empty'=>'--Select--',
                                                    'class'=>'form-control',
                                                        'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                                    'url'=>$this->createUrl('MarkDetails/CreateTestView'),
                                                                    'data'=>'js:$("#StudentTracker_student_track_class_branch").val()',
                                                                    'update'=>'#detail'
                                                                    )
                                                    )
                                                ); ?>
```

Try this one.

Comment: Not working the action what i have given in url is not functioning

Comment: @Jazz Try expanding your answer.